# Is patacake game called ぬすんではらいて

Tags: translation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pat-a-cake,_pat-a-cake,_baker%27s_man

Its recorded on Fisher Price toy TV remote control. That's what my Japanese wife says but she doesn't speak slowly so I can't be sure. I have no hits on Google search so it that right? If not what is the correct name?

Comment: むすんでひらいて I guess

Comment: Could you maybe ask your wife to speak slowly before asking here?

Comment: Are you wanting to ask about Pat-a-cake or about nursery rhymes in general?

Comment: If you want to know about むすんでひらいて, watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oypsXiOM3S0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a children's song called "むすんでひらいて" (musunde hiraite)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oypsXiOM3S0

むすぶ(musubu)＝tie a knot ("make a fist")

ひらく(hiraku)＝open [something]

The song title in English is "open your hand and close your hand"

P.S. Tho I do like your song title! "steal and open" :D

Comment: So does this mean that Japanese really don't have have a similar game to that in the West https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeYBmJPswe0 If they do what is it called- its a partner game with partner hand contact.

Comment: @user2617804 "Yankie Doodle" is known as アルプス一万尺【いちまんじゃく】 (lit. "Ten thousand feet Alpine") in Japan, and is very famous: https://youtu.be/Z57Mf2934-w But it doesn't sound like ぬすんではらいて at all...

Comment: @user2617804 `If they do what is it called- its a partner game with partner hand contact.` It's called [手遊]{てあそ}び[歌]{うた}. https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AB%A5%E6%AD%8C#2.E4.BA.BA.E7.B5.84.E3.81.A7.E9.81.8A.E3.81.B6.E6.89.8B.E9.81.8A.E3.81.B3.E6.AD.8C アルプス一万尺、みかんの花、茶摘み are 2人組で遊ぶ手遊び歌 (手遊び歌 that you play with a partner). むすんでひらいて is a 手遊び歌 too, but you don't need a partner to play it.